# Material-UI : Multiple select component with user selected order

Tags: material-ui, material-design

The idea is to have Select component with multiple selects with user select order.

If you have items : A,B,C,D,E

An end user could choose to have selected A,E as well as E,A. Both are not the same.

Any hint's or ideas are welcomed.